# How to block safe mode in android

Tags: android, mdm, safe-mode

My application is meant for applying some policies on android device and this application is managed by Admin using console.

Here the issue is user starts the phone in safe mode and uninstall the my application get rid of all the policies. Which I don't want.

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue.

Or

If I can stop users from uninstalling my app in safe mode that would also solve the purpose.

Note: My application already has Device Administrator rights.

Answer (score -2):

Since that's hard-wired into [Android](https://source.android.com/source/), you have two options:

- I think that the only way is to decompile the OS and comment out the safe mode code. (A really hard solution)
- Install your app as a System app.

Comment: How to install the app as a system app ?

Comment: and how that will disable safe mode.